# Have a property pointing to another property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, properties

In my iPhone project, I have a common "date editing" view which features a UIDatePicker. I would like to use this view to update one NSDate property based on the way it's called.

The way I thought about achieving that is to have an NSDate property called CurrentlyEditedDate which I set to point to the correct NSDate property I could like to edit. But I don't know how to do that.

Let's say I have 2 NSDate properties defined:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *startDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *endDate;
```

When I launch my view I would like to do the following:

```
CurrentlyEditedDate = startDate
```

Or the following based on the caller:

```
CurrentlyEditedDate = endDate
```

So that my view can edit any NSDate object. However I don't know how to define or assign the CurrentlyEditedDate property. Nor do I know how to set it up from the view to a new NSDate value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think actually the best solution here would be to implement a delegate protocol. It looks a little thornier, but it won't be as fragile as trying to store the variable reference.

Here's what you need to do:

First, declare the protocol so that other classes know what to implement in order to receive your delegate messages. Also, create a .delegate property so that other objects can tell your date picker that they want to get those messages:

```
// MyDatePicker.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class MyDatePicker;
@protocol MyDatePickerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myDatePicker:(MyDatePicker *)datePicker didChangeDate:(NSDate *)date;
@end

@interface MyDatePickerViewController : UIViewController {
    id<MyDatePickerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyDatePickerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Then when you get a new date from your picker, you just need to check to see if you have a delegate, and that they have implemented your method. If they have, just go ahead and tell them about the new date:

```
// MyDatePickerViewController.m
#import "MyDatePickerViewController.h"

@implementation MyDatePickerViewController

- (void)changedDate:(NSDate *)newDate {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDatePicker:didChangeDate:)]) {
        [delegate myDatePicker:self didChangeDate:newDate];
    }
}

@end
```

Then, in your class where you want to receive the date info you might do something like this:

```
- (void)createDatePicker {
    MyDatePicker *datePicker = [[MyDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.delegate = self;
}

- (void)myDatePicker:(MyDatePicker *)datePicker didChangeDate:(NSDate *)date {

    if (startTimeOrSomething) {
        self.startDate = date;
    } else {
        self.endDate = date;
    }
}
```

I just typed that without compiling, but it should be correct. This may seem like a lot of work, but it will very quickly become second nature, and is a much more robust way to handle these kinds of situations.

Comment: Thanks. This works very well and is an elegant solution. Plus, I've learned how to create custom delegates. Minor typos though: "class" = "@class" and "MyDatePickerViewController" is not an NSObject but a UIViewController.

Comment: Glad it helped, and thanks for catching those. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the `setCurrentlyEditedDate:(NSDate* date)` method that exists as a result of creating the property.

```
[myDateViewController setCurrentlyEditedDate: startDate];
```

If you call this where you create and initialize the view controller for the date picker, it will assign the `NSDate` property (which is a pointer already) to point to the `startDate` `NSDate` object.

Comment: I'm not sure how to declare the currentlyEditedDate property. Is it a nonatomic retain property ?Also, it doesn't seem to work, perhaps because I don't correctly set the date back in my view controller when it has changed from the picker. I do: delegate.currentlyEditedDate = datePicker.date;